# Group by Functionality on Mac Address

Tags: text-processing, sort

I'm looking for a solution that should do grouping of identical mac address(device ids). I tried using `sort -k 2`, but I'm not confident of the result.

Data Set looks like:

```
1616.93,ac:22:0b:a6:22:c3
2872.32,c0:bd:d1:36:bb:49
3314.55,d4:0b:1a:39:19:b2
2854.11,18:f6:43:64:81:67
3540.68,18:f6:43:64:81:67
3856.91,ac:22:0b:a6:22:c3
2497.93,d4:0b:1a:39:19:b2
```

Expected Output

```
1616.93,ac:22:0b:a6:22:c3
3856.91,ac:22:0b:a6:22:c3
3314.55,d4:0b:1a:39:19:b2
2497.93,d4:0b:1a:39:19:b2
2872.32,c0:bd:d1:36:bb:49
2854.11,18:f6:43:64:81:67
3540.68,18:f6:43:64:81:67
```

Follow up question: After grouping it by device ids, if I have to sort column 1 in ascending order. how should I go about that

Comment: Whats the condition for sorting ? do you want the output as you shown or you are satisfied with the devices grouped according to group IDs ?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide solution as per the output shown

Comment: Check my answer..how do you want to change that now? there seems to be no common points..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sort -t"," -k 2 file
2854.11,18:f6:43:64:81:67
3540.68,18:f6:43:64:81:67
1616.93,ac:22:0b:a6:22:c3
3856.91,ac:22:0b:a6:22:c3
2872.32,c0:bd:d1:36:bb:49
2497.93,d4:0b:1a:39:19:b2
3314.55,d4:0b:1a:39:19:b2
```

Just needed to use `-t","` as the delimiter.
And `file` stores your unsorted data.

Comment: follow up question: lets say after sorting it with device ids, if I have to sort the colomn 1 in ascending order, how would I do that? like the expected output, I have shown